# Showing that $\int_0^\infty$ $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$ $dx = 1$

Tags: probability, integration, exponential-function

Show the pdf is a valid pdf of an exponential random variable by showing that

$\int_0^\infty$ $\frac{1}{\theta}e^\frac{-x}{\theta}$ $dx = 1$

Comment: Any thoughts?  Do you know how to compute $\int e^{-cx}dx$?

Comment: Perform the substitution $u = -\frac{x}{\theta}$ and maybe it won't look so difficult...

Answer (score 2):

One may recall that
$$
\int e^{\lambda x}dx= \frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda},\quad \lambda \neq0
$$ giving
$$
\int\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\large\frac{-x}{\theta}}\:dx=\frac{1}{\theta}\int e^{\large-\frac{x}{\theta}}\:dx=?
$$